# Best way to import public module folder using visual studio C++ 20

Tags: c++, visual-studio, module, c++20

There's a folder(D:\repos) contains a lot of module folders,mymath,mymath2 and myetc.

What's the best way to import mymath to my new project?

D:\repos\mymath\mymath.ixx:

```
export module mymath
import std.core;
namespace mymath{
  export void add() { std::cout << "mymath add called\n"; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

According to [Mcicrosoft Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/a-tour-of-cpp-modules-in-visual-studio/), you could use the modules on disk according to the following steps.

**External Modules**

It is also possible to reference modules that exist on disk, instead of ones belonging to another project in the solution. Care needs to be taken here, however, because modules are compiled, binary files. You must make sure they are compatible with the way you are building your projects.

You can tell Visual Studio to look for modules on disk by editing the Additional Module Dependencies property:

[image]

Also, you could refer to this [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/standard-c20-modules-support-with-msvc-in-visual-studio-2019-version-16-8/#module-linkage) for more information about `module`.

Comment: I'm sorry to provide you with the wrong information. However,  I finally found the information about modules in the Microsoft Blog. Hope it  could help you.